# Deformation matrix, Math hack for stability on large simulation steps?

Tags: numerics, simulation, numerical-limitations, calculus

So there is a numeric technique for updating a deformation gradient in MPM that goes as:

$$F_{n+1} = (I + \nabla \vec v \Delta t)F_n$$

This works for small time steps but for large time steps numerical issues ensue. One of the biggest issues is that I assume that the deformation matrix always has a determinant of one, but for large time steps it can flip the sign.

I am looking for a numerically stable (accuracy does not matter) way to modify the matrix. Basically if the determinant is negative, I want to tweak the resulting $F_{n+1}$ matrix such that its determinant is now positive, and it remains stable in terms of the overall simulation.

The discrete formula comes from the differential equation:

$$\frac{dF}{dt} = \nabla \vec v F$$

I am not sure if I can leverage the analysis to self correct for the determinant.

Comment: Try implicit Euler, you'll have to solve a linear system however. For very large time steps this may be cheaper than doing many small time steps with explicit Euler however. I have to idea what objects F and v are in your question by the way, from what I read $F$ seems to be a matrix, but what is $\nabla \vec{v}$ then? Is it some kind of Jacobian matrix?

Comment: $F$ is the deformation gradient, $\nabla \vec v$ is the gradient of the velocity field (similar to a jacobian matrix). I cannot do implicit Euler, it takes far too much time.

Comment: If you have multiple steps you can try to apply something like fast explicit diffusion: https://www.mia.uni-saarland.de/Research/SC_FED.shtml or the scheduled jacobi relaxation method. I don't know whether it will work well for your problem though. Beyond that you can make the resolution of your grid coarser (if your matrices arise from a grid discretisation). Is $\nabla v$ fixed by thevway or does it change between steps? What is it a function of? What did you use for the implicit system solution that it was so slow? Have you tried a Jacobi preconditioner instead of just Richardson?

Comment: I am doing MLS-MPM, simulating a fluid with 50k particles doing one simulaiton step per frame at 60 fps. $\nabla v$ changes between time steps it;s the velocity of the particles when transported ot the grid. I did not implement it, I read an article by the creator of the MLS-MPM method which said it's likely not even worth trying.

Comment: If $\nabla v$ is a matrix of the velocities of the particles how is it square? Isn't a velocity a $d$-dimensional vector and you have $N$ particles, so $d\times N$? Anyways assume for a second that $\nabla v$ was a fixed matrix $-A$, then the iteration that you have is convergent for $\|I-\Delta t A\|<1$, that's generally where the step size constraint comes from, for a symmetric positive definite $A$ and the $2$-norm this generally translates to $\Delta t \in (0, 2/\lambda_{max})$. You can't avoid this with explicit Euler, unless you consider a multistep relaxation method as mentioned.

Comment: $\nabla v$ is square because it's teh gradient of a vector funciton in n variables. For example in 2D v is a vector function of 2 variables, it's gradient is thus a 2x2 matrix made by the gradietn of the first coordinate funciton and the second.

It is computed per particle, not for all particles.

Comment: For me a particle is described by a position vector $\vec{p}(t)\in\mathbb{R}^d$ that is a function of time. The velocity of a particle is then $d_t p(t)\in\mathbb{R}^d$. I am probably misunderstanding what you mean by "velocity of the particles when transported on the grid". The only thing I can suggest are acceleration strategies, i.e. the link I mentioned, or you can also try and interpret it as gradient descent $F_{n+1} = F_n + \Delta t \nabla v F_n$ with step size $\Delta t$ and gradient $\nabla v F_n$, and e.g. apply Nesterov's heavy ball method to this.

Comment: MPM methods are hybrid methods, they use both g a grid and particles to simulate the system. in this case $v$ is the velocity field on the grid (as oposed to the velocity field on each particle)

Comment: Do tell if the fast explicit diffusion, or scheduled relaxed Jacobi, or Nesterov help. I am curious to know. If you interpret this as a gradient descent scheme you can also look into conjugate gradients: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_conjugate_gradient_method
I am not sure how applicable this is to your problem however since you're not really solving a minimization problem but some kind of evolution equation. For reference - I don't think the determinant is the issue per se - it's just you violating the stability constraints for explicit Euler as illustrated with the $A$.

Comment: This looks like explicit Euler. Its stability region (circle of radius 1 around -1) only touches the imaginary line. This means that for some eigenvalues the range of admissible step sizes becomes arbitrarily small. Use a higher order explicit method. The stability region of RK4 for example includes a half-circle of diameter 2.5 around the origin which increases the chance to get step sizes that are admissible for all eigenvalues of the system matrix $∇\vec v$.

Comment: Did this lead anywhere? Or did you gave up on trying to speed it up?

Comment: @lightxbulb I ran into a paper which basically says that currently there exist no reliable methods to do this for large time steps in a stable manner. So I gave up.

Answer (score 4):

The part about your 'stability' requirements seems impossible to answer without more detail. But if you just want to ensure that $\det F_{n+1} = 1$ at each step, then a quick fix is scaling your update rule to ensure that this property holds:
$$
F_{n+1} = \alpha(I + \nabla \vec v \Delta t)F_n,
$$
where $\alpha>0$ is chosen so that
$$
\det \alpha(I + \nabla \vec v \Delta t) = 1.
$$
If $\nabla \vec v$ and $\Delta t$ are vectors, you can compute the determinant quickly with the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma). Then don't forget to scale correctly: for an $m\times m$ matrix $A$, $\det \alpha A = \alpha^m \det A$.

Comment: if m is squared this means that if the determinant is negative then then there's no way to find $\alpha$ such that $\alpha A$ = 1. since ti will always be negative.

Comment: True (I assume you mean if $m$ is *even*). I have no idea how your simulation works, but I assumed that the determinant got negative because of the combined uncorrected effect of several time steps, not just of a single one.